# Condensing Table Array Rows in BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery, ansi-sql

**I want to use BigQuery Standard SQL**

I have a table that looks like:

[image]

How would I collapse each row? For or instance, so that row #1 looks something like:

```
row   Canopus_id    facebook     id      wikipedia    freebase musicbrainz    
1      10043474     21258...    Q557     Patt_Smith     /m/05qw5  d1358...
```

Essentially we are collapsing the row in such a way that it will try to find a filled entry for a column and if there is a filled entry (either in the first or second cell) that will be the value. Else, there will be a null.

Comment: is every shown column actually a separate repeated field or it is one repeated record? - would be great to see schema of the table/data

Comment: @javacash . . . I'm curious what the types of the columns are.  Arrays don't support `NULL` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select row,
       (select max(facebook) from unnest(facebook) facebook) as facebook,
       (select max(id) from unnest(id) id) as id,
       . . .
from t;
```